# Scraping <li> elements with Rvest

Tags: r, rvest

Good morning,

I'm new to scraping with R, and I'm having a hard time to scrape a list of elements from a webpage in a useful manner.

This is my script

```
library(rvest)

url <- read_html("https://www.pole-emploi.fr/annuaire/provins-77070")

webpage <- url %>%
  html_nodes('.zone') %>%
  html_text()
webpage
```

When I run the script all the elements appear squeezed together without any whitespace between, which is comprehensible since each item is enclosed in a single

tag.

```
 [1] "77114GouaixHerméNoyen-sur-SeineVilliers-sur-Seine"                                                                                                                                 
 [2] "77118BalloyBazoches-lès-BrayGravon"
```

I would like to have them either like this (or separated by commas)

```
[1] "77114 Gouaix Hermé Noyen-sur-Seine Villiers-sur-Seine"                                                                                                                                 
[2] "77118 Balloy Bazoches-lès-Bray Gravon"
```

Or even better on a tidy format

```
 Postal City
 77114  Gouaix
 77114  Hermé
 77114  Noyen-sur-Seine
 77114  Villiers-sur-Seine
```

I have tried to find other selector or Xpaths in the page without success. The most I have got is to select one single element of the list.

Any help would be greatly apprecaited.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each list element looks like this (truncated for brevity):

```
<li class="zone">\n<span class="code-postal">77114</span><ul>\n<li>Gouaix</li>\n<li>Hermé</li>\n ...
```

So, each one has a set of child nodes that look uniform. We can target the `<span>` and the `<li>` elements in the nested `<ul>` to get what you want:

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

pg <- read_html("https://www.pole-emploi.fr/annuaire/provins-77070")

html_nodes(pg, ".zone") %>% 
  map_df(~{
    data_frame(
      postal = html_node(.x, "span") %>% html_text(trim=TRUE),
      city = html_nodes(.x, "ul > li") %>% html_text(trim=TRUE)
    )
  }) 
## # A tibble: 95 x 2
##    postal city                 
##    <chr>  <chr>                
##  1 77114  Gouaix               
##  2 77114  Hermé                
##  3 77114  Noyen-sur-Seine      
##  4 77114  Villiers-sur-Seine   
##  5 77118  Balloy               
##  6 77118  Bazoches-lès-Bray    
##  7 77118  Gravon               
##  8 77126  Châtenay-sur-Seine   
##  9 77126  Égligny              
## 10 77134  Les Ormes-sur-Voulzie
## # ... with 85 more rows
```

the tidyverse method with explicit anonymous function (vs `.x` via formula function):

```
html_nodes(pg, ".zone") %>% 
  map_df(function(x) {
    data_frame(
      postal = html_node(x, "span") %>% html_text(trim=TRUE),
      city = html_nodes(x, "ul > li") %>% html_text(trim=TRUE)
    )
  })
```

and, a pure base R version:

```
elements <- html_nodes(pg, ".zone")
lapply(elements, function(x) {
  data.frame(
    postal = html_text(html_node(x, "span"), trim=TRUE),
    city = html_text(html_nodes(x, "ul > li"), trim=TRUE),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )
}) -> tmp

Reduce(rbind.data.frame, tmp)

# or

do.call(rbind.data.frame, tmp)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was very useful . Just one more question, is the .x in  html_node(.x, "span") a placeholder for forwarding ".zone" to this nested html_node element ?  Thanks again.

Comment: I added 2 additional solutions that hopefully help show what's going on. The "~{}" in the main example is a tidyverse `purrr` "formula function" which has an implicit variable name of `.x` (or just `.`) that can be used. It's syntactic sugar to aid in code brevity but, like the `_` in Scala code, it just "pops up a variable out of nowhere" and is definitely confusing at first sight.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the added comments. This is much clear now.