# Scraping Twitter Links from multiple URLs, using Purrr Map - Error in UseMethod("xml_find_first")

Tags: r, purrr, rvest

I have a dataset that contains URLs of profiles of politicians in the German parliament. Many of these profiles also include links to the politician's Twitter pages. I want to create a loop, or ideally using purrr::map(), that scrapes the Twitter links adding it as a new column to the original dataset.

I've found several code examples that do something similar:

- [Scraping of Multi-page websites](https://webscraping-tures.github.io/rvest3.html#index-pages)
- [Scraper.R scraping politicians twitter profiles](https://github.com/WZBSocialScienceCenter/mdb-twitter-network/commit/43b45b58c7a389184f80e40ba833da48cfb31db8)
- [Scraping li elements with Rvest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52650604/scraping-li-elements-with-rvest)

But I cannot get them to run with my own data.

Taking a small sample of the URLs from the dataframe, I've converted thems to a vector, which looks like this:

```
> links
[1] "https://www.abgeordnetenwatch.de/profile/julia-obermeier"    
[2] "https://www.abgeordnetenwatch.de/profile/anja-weisgerber"    
[3] "https://www.abgeordnetenwatch.de/profile/klaus-ernst"        
[4] "https://www.abgeordnetenwatch.de/profile/astrid-freudenstein"
```

Not all of the URLs have links to the politicians Twitter profile and missing links would be ideally returned as NA.

This is my attempt:

```
pages <- links %>% map(read_html)
```

The result is a list of 4. Next to get a dataframe containing the twitter links and politicians names(so I can merge them with the original dataset) I try the following code:

```
pages %>% map_df(~{
  data_frame(name = html_node(pages, "h1") %>% html_text(trim=TRUE) %>%
               html_node(pages, "href") %>% html_text(trim=TRUE))})

#Error in UseMethod("xml_find_first") : 
#no applicable method for 'xml_find_first' applied to an object of class "list"
```

I think the issue is the HTML being in a list rather than a vector, but haven't found a solution to convert it while maintaining the original intent of returning a dataframe.

I also know from doing it step by step on one URL, that the code scrapes numerous links when I only want the URL of the politicians twitter profile, but I think that's something that can be easily fixed when I have the dataframe.

An overall more refined solution would be much appreciated.

Really any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can't apply `html_nodes` on an `html_text` result.
This works :

```
ages %>% map_df(~{
  data_frame(name = html_node(.x, "h1") %>% html_text(trim=TRUE) 
               )})

# A tibble: 4 × 1
  name               
  <chr>              
1 Julia Obermeier    
2 Anja Weisgerber    
3 Klaus Ernst        
4 Astrid Freudenstein
```